# TimeStamp booking - start_time & end_time

Tags: laravel

I would like to use the timestamp for my booking system. Here is my fields different.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('trainings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->date('date_seance');
        $table->time('hour_start');
        $table->time('hour_end');
        $table->integer('fk_motorbike')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('fk_motorbike')->references('id')->on('motorbikes');
        $table->integer('fk_former')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('fk_former')->references('id')->on('formers');
        $table->integer('fk_student')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('fk_student')->references('id')->on('students');
        $table->integer('fk_typeseance')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('fk_typeseance')->references('id')->on('typeseances');
        $table->timestamp('start_time');
        $table->timestamp('stop_time');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In my form `Training`, I enter a recording for example.

### Training Form:

```
id |   date_seance  |     hour_start  |   hour_end
 1      15/09/2019           18:00          20:00
```

If I want to enter another recording for the samen date, I have a duplicate.

### Training Form:

```
id |   date_seance  |     hour_start  |   hour_end
 1      15/09/2019           18:00          20:00
 2      15/09/2019           08:00          10:00
```

I don't understand why?

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'date_seance' => 'required',
        'hour_start' => 'required',
        'hour_end' => 'required',
        'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
        'fk_former' => 'required',
        'fk_student' => 'required',
        'fk_typeseance' => 'required'
    ]);

    $start_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_seance . ' ' . $hour_start);
    $stop_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_seance . ' ' . $hour_end);

    $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->fk_motorbike)
        ->where('start_time', "<=", $start_time)
        ->where('stop_time', ">=", $stop_time)
        ->first();

    if (isset($conflictTraining)) {
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'In training');
    }

    $data = $request->all();
    $data['start_time'] = $start_time;
    $data['stop_time'] = $stop_time;
    Training::create($data);
    return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
        ->with('success', 'Add');
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is difficult to understand exactly what problem you're experiencing. You may need to add more code or further explanation of what you're expecting vs. what is actually happening. Also, you mention `start_time` & `end_time` fields, but are showing us `hour_start` & `hour_end` in your database row example.

Comment: is that code complete? cause if so, `$date_seance`, `$hour_start`, `$hour_end` - aren't those undefined? Also, looking at your second query (considering everything else is OK), that query will not return a conflicting row, based on the hours you passed. Also, those records are not duplicated. As @AkenRoberts said, please spend time to edit your question, it's vague and not easily understandable.